# Valgrind Invalid read of size 4

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, runtime-error, valgrind

Here is code for my BirthDate.cpp File I have 3 Files in total this is first one

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "BirthDate.h"
//#include "File.h"
using namespace std;

namespace sdds{
    int TotalRecords;
    info* birthdays;
    int globalmonth;
    FILE* fptr;


  bool openFile(const char filename[]) {
      fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
      return fptr != NULL;
   }
   
   int noOfRecords() {
      int noOfRecs = 0;
      char ch;
      while (fscanf(fptr, "%c", &ch) == 1) {
         noOfRecs += (ch == '\n');
      }
      rewind(fptr);
      return noOfRecs;
   }
   
   void closeFile() {
      if (fptr) fclose(fptr);
   }

   bool read(char *stuName) {
      return fscanf(fptr, "%[^,],", stuName) == 1;
   }

   bool read(int &stumonth) {
      return fscanf(fptr, "%d/", &stumonth) == 1;
   }
   
   bool load(info &birthdays){
        char sname[128];
        if(read(sname) && read(birthdays.month) && read(birthdays.date) && read(birthdays.year)){
            birthdays.b_name = new char[strlen(sname) + 1];
            strcpy(birthdays.b_name, sname);
            
            // for(int i=0;i<(int)strlen(sname);i++){
            //         birthdays.b_name[i] = birthdays.b_name[i+1];
            // }
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool beginSearch(const char *filename){
        globalmonth = 0;
        TotalRecords = 0;
        int i=0,j=0;
        if(openFile(filename)){
            TotalRecords = noOfRecords();
            birthdays = new info[TotalRecords];  // this is where error is occuring
            for(j=0;j<TotalRecords;j++){
                i += load(birthdays[j]);
            }
            if(i!=TotalRecords){
                cout<<"Error: incorrect number of records read; the data is possibly corrupted.\n";
            }
            closeFile();
        }
        cout<<"Birthdate search program\n";
        return true;
    }

    bool readBirthDate(int month){
        for(int i=0;i<TotalRecords;i++){
            if(birthdays[i].month==month){
                globalmonth = month;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    void sort(){
       // sort the array by year and then by month
         int i, j;
            info temp;
            for (i = TotalRecords - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (birthdays[j].year > birthdays[j + 1].year) {
                        temp = birthdays[j];
                        birthdays[j] = birthdays[j + 1];
                        birthdays[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                    else if (birthdays[j].year == birthdays[j + 1].year && birthdays[j].month > birthdays[j + 1].month) {
                        temp = birthdays[j];
                        birthdays[j] = birthdays[j + 1];
                        birthdays[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    void displayBirthdays(){
        //count the number of records where months == globalmonth
        int count=0,ind = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<TotalRecords;i++){
            if(birthdays[i].month==globalmonth){
                count++;
            }
        }
        cout<<count<<" birthdates found:\n";
        for(int i=0;i<126;i++){
        if(birthdays[i].month==globalmonth){
           cout<<ind<<") ";
           string s;
           for(int j=1;j<(int)strlen(birthdays[i].b_name);j++){
               s += birthdays[i].b_name[j];
           }
           cout<<s<<":"<<endl;
           cout<<birthdays[i].year<<"-"<<birthdays[i].month<<"-"<<birthdays[i].date<<endl;
           cout<<"===================================\n";
           ind++;
         }
        }
    }
    void deallocate(){
        
        for(int i=0;i<TotalRecords;i++){
            delete[] birthdays[i].b_name;
        }
        delete[] birthdays;
        
    }
    void endSearch(){
        cout<<"Birthdate Search Program Closed.\n";
    }
}
```

Here is my code for BirthDate.h File this is my second file

```
#ifndef SDDS_BIRTHDATE_H
#define SDDS_BIRTHDATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace sdds{

   struct info{
       char *b_name;
       int month;
       int date;
       int year;
   };
   bool openFile(const char filename[]);
   void closeFile();
   int noOfRecords();
  
   //for reading name
   bool read(char *stuName);

   //for reading student number
   bool read(int &stumonth);
    bool beginSearch(const char *filename);
    bool readBirthDate(int month);
    void sort();
    void displayBirthdays();
    void deallocate();
    void endSearch();
}
#endif
```

And it is my main.cpp file and this my 3rd and last file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BirthDate.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;
int main() {
   bool done = false;
   int month = 0;
   char filename[256];
   cout << "V1.1 corrected the data file records" << endl;
   cout << "Enter data file name: ";
   cin >> filename;
   if (beginSearch(filename)) {
      while (!done) {
         cout << "Enter a month of birth or 0 to exit: ";
         cin >> month;
         if (month == 0) {
            done = true;
         }
         else {
            if (readBirthDate(month)) {
               sort();
               displayBirthdays();
               deallocate();
            }
            else {
               cout << "No match found!" << endl;
            }
         }
      }
      endSearch();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

So whenever I run this code in Visual Studio Code it runs perfectly but when i try to check memory leak with Valgrind it shows this error.

```
==111737== Invalid read of size 4
==111737==    at 0x40143D: sdds::displayBirthdays() (BirthDate.cpp:120)
==111737==    by 0x4017B1: main (main_prof.cpp:32)
==111737==  Address 0x5afeac0 is 8 bytes after a block of size 3,000 alloc'd
==111737==    at 0x4C2AC38: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
==111737==    by 0x401019: sdds::beginSearch(char const*) (BirthDate.cpp:67)
==111737==    by 0x401766: main (main_prof.cpp:22)
==111737==
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<126;i++){` Why are you using a hardcoded magic number like `126`? What do you think will happen when `TotalRecords` is less than 126?

Comment: @kaylum Ohh Thanks it works, I am trying to figure out this for last 1 hour and it's done now Thanks again

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of allocating an array yourself.

Comment: @kaylum can you help me solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502870/can-help-me-to-fix-valgrind-memory-leak